# How to remove files with special characters Shell script

Tags: shell

From a shell linux script, I need help to read the file /tmp/sandrox/current.txt and remove each file listed:

The content of the file /tmp/sandrox/current.txt is:

```
"1"
"2"
"4"
"5"
"6"
"nueva\ linea?\ \\n\ aqui"
"intel.com"
"7"
"8"
```

This is the script I am using to read the file but, I am unable to delete the **"nueva\ linea?\ \n\ aqui"** because it has special characters and white spaces. Is there a way to remove files without any problems? Including files with special characters? In this case those are the special characters but is impossible to determine what will be the next special characters used in another file listed.

```
while read file; do
    if grep -Fxq "$file" "/tmp/sandrox/keep.txt"; then
        dummy=null # dummy variable because this conditional can not be empty
    else
        echo "Deleting $file"
        #rm -rf "$root/$file"
    fi
done < "/tmp/sandrox/current.txt"
```

Comment: are the double-quotes part of the actual filenames?

Comment: Use `ls -i` to see what inode number each file is.  You can then delete the files with `find -inum YOUR-NUMBER -delete`.  Using -print0 with find is useful as well (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)